# SSRS - simulate slicers using filtering

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I've seen websites explain how to use a tablix to list possible parameters for a report (another tablix) to simulate slicers. This technique relies on passing parameters and the report being refreshed.

The issue is, this is slow for where I want to use it.  I am wondering if there is a way to load all the data for my report and then use a similar technique to create a slicer to limit the data using the filter on the dataset.

Another option I thought about was simply hiding the rows that didn't match what was selected in the "slicer".

Comment: X->Y problem in the house. SSRS isn't designed for client-side interaction. Why not use an actual dashboarding tool like Power View or PowerBI or DataZen?

Comment: We are also using Power Bi, but it is very limited for reports. You can't even control what columns it subtotals on.  I wish they'd add better traditional report support.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to speed up the processing time is to use caching. Go to "Manage Processing Options" in your report manager (or SharePoint, depending on what you're using). Set it to use cached data. Play around with the duration and cache refresh schedule settings to suit your situation.

You may also benefit from applying your parameters as Dataset filters as opposed to passing them into the query. This can help ensure that a cached version of the report will be available. It really depends on how big the dataset is and how many combinations of parameters you're trying to allow.